# How to pass params to child window through ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a requirement where I have a parent window with a button. Clicking on the button performs some logic, computes some values and opens a child window with those params. I'm trying to find a good way to do this. My current implementation is as follows.

Inside my ng-click method I have

```
let location = this.$state.href('moveout', { entityUuid: this.entityUuid, count: count, params: params, options: options);
let unDockedWindow = this.$window.open(location, '', 'scrollbars=no,fullscreen=yes,toolbar=no');
```

This successfully opens a child window with url that looks like the below

```
#/moveout?entityUuid=8eb6c75e-5a06-333c-a4cf-a97d90995722&count=something&params=something&options=something
```

I'm able to access the data in the destination like so

```
$state.params.entityUuid
```

My problem however is that, some of these attributes can be complex, like params and options. And I don't necessary want to have a url that has so many params and looks really ugly.

I'm trying to see if there is a way to open a child window with a number of params with ui-router without passing them as query string params.

I don't think I want to use ui-sref since some of the values that need to be passed need to be computed based on some logic. Hence doing it inside ng-click.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you thought about local storage ?

Comment: Using a service to store the parameters that you need is a better option than local storage imo.  Using a service is generally the preferred method for sharing data between controllers. [walkthrough of how to do this](https://daveceddia.com/sharing-data-between-controllers-best-practice-use-a-service/)

Comment: You can use broadcast event to pass your values from parent controller to child controller

Comment: I'm trying to get data in my child windows. Each child window is a new instance of the application. So data cannot be shared between them. Local storage however seems like a good idea. @Ash, I'll try it out and write back if it works.

Comment: @Ash, local storage worked perfectly for my scenario. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark the question as answered. Thanks!